# How safely remove a USB flash disk via the command line

Tags: ubuntu, usb

If your shell script helps you to **safely remove your flash disk** after finishing its job. The solution is expected to meet the following needs:

1. Suppose the flash disk is mounted as `/media/A` together with many other flash disks, and the code can selectively just remove `/media/A` without interfering other disks. For example, I can pass `/media/A` as an argument.
2. A light solution. Installing another package of size 100 MB to finish the task drives one crazy.
3. I know some commands like `hdparm` except their documents are hard to read. If one can offer me a solution, I hope he/she can offer also the explanation of the parameters, etc.
4. Best if the code can handle all kinds of flash disks (for example, my old one bought in 2003 with 32 MB) (and portable disks optionally).
5. It should achieve the exact effect as right-clicking the disk → clicking "*safely Remove Drive*". The safety concern will prevail, otherwise one may just unplug the disk, which usually won't hurt.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `umount`?  As in, `umount /media/A`.  The command might be hidden a bit out of the way (perhaps `/sbin` instead of `/bin`), but it is a fundamental command and is likely to be in one of those two (or, possibly, `/usr/sbin`).

Comment: After umounting, the flash disk is still not ready for remove. This link is the best explanation I ever saw: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5845/what-is-the-difference-between-unmount-eject-safely-remove-drive-and-the It seems to me that this is because of the USB power supply. So the disk disappears from nautilus yet removing it is just not "safe".

Comment: After unmounting, you can unplug it. The only thing that would still be going through the wires should be power. if it's not, something is seriously wrong with your computer.

Comment: Cole would you please give me some reference? A comprehensive ref list will form an excellent answer.

Comment: Use `pumount`, which comes with `usbmount`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do this using udisks. It is not installed by default, but it is easy enough to install (the package is like a megabyte in size once installed)...

```
sudo apt-get install udisks
```

Once installed, you can detach a USB drive with the following commands...

```
sudo udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
sudo udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

The first line unmounts it. Just like any other partition you can still remount it at this point. The second line detaches it. After this it is powered down and you have to remove/reinsert it to remount.

To clarify, *sdb* is the device and *sdb1*, *sdb2*, *sdb3*, etc. are partitions on the device. Also, you will need to unmount all mount points before you attempt to detach the device. Usually with a USB stick/drive there is only one but it is a warning you should know about none the less.

Getting the device name from the mount point would require you pull it from mount or something.

Comment: I found it still works without `sudo`. Another question, it is save that I assume the second location `/dev/sdb` could always be obtained by dropping the last number from the first location: `/dev/sdb1` ?

Comment: Yeah sdb is the device and sdb1 is the partition on the device. You should note though if you have multiple partitions mounted on the same device the second step will probably fail.

Comment: You can also use the command `eject`. It gives an error message but it seems to work exactly as requested (unmounts and will not automatically remount).

[I can't add a new answer because it's closed, but this is the top link on google so it seems like the best place to add this.]

Comment: `eject` worked, where `udisks` gave me a weird `STOP UNIT: FAILED: No such file` error. Debian 7 Wheezy here.

Comment: When using the last command it powers down my device but immediately powers it back up again, suggestions?

Comment: Causes issues with some internal laptop SD card readers that are mounted on startup even without a card in them, as they get disconnected so u have to reboot to mount them again (or find and mount the device if possible). Works though thanks!

Comment: Since my edit for modern distributions was rejected. Here is the info unformatted:

 If your distribution uses udisks2 use these commands instead:

`sudo apt-get install udisks2`
`sudo udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1`
`sudo udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb`